# Why use SEL action = sel_registerName("doSomething:")?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just wonder why write as

```
SEL sel = @selector (start:) ;  
if ([obj respondsToSelector:sel]) {  
    [obj performSelector:sel withObject:self];  
}
```

especially in `XIB`, the drag drop `IBAction` is enough

what is advantage using SEL?

Comment: What does the posted code have to with a xib or an `IBAction`?

Comment: Do you mean: why use it instead of [obj start:self] ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not required to do this; in Objective-C, an object is not required to respond to a given select (i.e. implement a method), and so if you attempt to invoke the selector, it may not work. This way, you politely ask the object whether it performs the given selector, and then invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

`SEL`, The data type (typedef) of a selector; this data type represents a method signature at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

An object may or may not support a method. If you call

```
[obj start:self];
```

and obj doesn't support the start: method, your app will crash. This code checks whether obj supports the start: method and calls it if it is supported. I would very much prefer to write

```
if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector (start:)) {  
    [obj start:self];  
}
```